# Make a table from from table A and table B where match

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL noob here. I need to create a product catalog table from two others.  Table A has a product weight and Table B has description.  So I need to make a Table C with the weight and description of course.

These catalogs are different, from different sources, and the only field I can match is SKU.

Should I make Table C from a copy of Table A (with weight), then add a description column, then:

```
update tableC  
join tableA on tableB.sku = tableA.sku  
set description = tableB.description
```

Comment: Of course! Or you could use a `SELECT ... JOIN`.

Comment: Will the `sku` values in `tablea` also exist in `tableb`, or do you need a `union` result (where some skus have weights and some have descriptions)?

Comment: Hi sgeddes, thanks - some have weights and some have descriptions, just as you say. Both have the sku - that's my only key.

Answer (score 3):

Creating another table to *copy* and hold values related to each other from two other tables is a poor approach. SQL is a *relational* language; you should leverage that to simply get both values from both tables:

```
SELECT
   tableA.weight
 , tableB.description
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB on tableB.sku = tableA.sku
```

No need to create a copy to relate the two in a whole other table. That's unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Jared thank you.  I meant to say that I'm creating a third table because that's the production one, and the other two are being grabbed remotely nightly.  I still need your fix though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
INSERT INTO
    TableC (`weight`,`desc`)
SELECT
    TableA.weight, TableB.desc
FROM
    TableA
    INNER JOIN
        TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id;
```

?

(see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: user3476487 do you mean id or sku?  sku is my only matching field.

Comment: Of course, you can use sku. Idea - compare records from "tableA" and "tableB" by product, if if have different id's and same sku field (sorry, not thinked about it) - you can use it.